# what is the matlab .' (dot-quote) notation?

Tags: matlab

Trying to understand MATLAB syntax: I see that

```
(0:3)
```

is a row vector, that the `'` (forward-quote) operator is `transpose`, so

```
(0:3)'
```

is a column vector.  I have also seen `.'` in some files, and these also produce column vectors, so

```
(0:3).'
```

produces the same result as `(0:3)`.

What is the difference between `'` and `.'`?  I haven't found anything in the MATLAB docs to help me understand this.

(note that this question is about syntax, primarily, not about the difference between `transpose` and `ctranspose`, because if you don't know that `'` is one and `.'` is the other, than an answer to the question of `transpose` versus `ctranspose` is of no help answering the question of `.` versus `'.`.  In many MATLAB examples and tutorials, `'` is glibly and inaccurately presented as `transpose`, and that fact leads to the question when a user first encounters `.'`.)

Comment: Quintessence: Always use `.'` and get used to it, unless you really know what you're doing and you really need `'`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference for real numbers. 
For complex numbers `.'` will produce transpose, while `'` will produce the [complex conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

```
>> [i -i].'

ans =

   0.0000 + 1.0000i
   0.0000 - 1.0000i

>> [i -i]'

ans =

   0.0000 - 1.0000i
   0.0000 + 1.0000i
```

By the way, each Matlab operator has a name, which can be used to read the documentation.

- `.'` - `transpose`
- `'` - `ctranspose`

Though it *is* hard to find them in the documentation sometimes.  Most of them can be found in [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/operators-and-elementary-operations.html), but you will have to guess which operator is which.

Comment: It would be brilliant if you found a Matlab resource that explains that `.'` is transpose and `'` is ctranspose.

Comment: @kkuilla, I agree. Still looking for it

Comment: @kkuilla Type `help punct`. Quoting: _X' is the complex conjugate transpose of X. X.' is the non-conjugate transpose._ BTW, congrats on your 1k rep!

Comment: @LuisMendo, thanks that looks good. But it does not cover function like `gt`,`lt`.

Comment: @Andrey That's `help relop`

Comment: @LuisMendo, cool! How about `+`? Maybe you could compile all of them into an answer? Maybe even starting a new question? That would be extremely helpful

Comment: @Andrey I think `+` does not belong to any general category: just `help plus`,  `help minus`, `help times` etc. Your suggestion sounds like a good idea, but I doubt what the question to that answer would be, or if it would be really useful

Comment: @Andrey Oh, there is such category: `help arith`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you. A milestone for me... :)